# How To Manipulate Multiple Tables From One Tabular Form In Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, tabular-form

I want to update two tables at a same time in tabular form. But without tabular MRD and MRU process, how can I work with the selected checkbox item?

Also how can I calculate total unit price of a product in tabular form , when quantity of that product are updated?

[image]

**Scenario:** When I click on "Add Item" button on left side then the tabular order generated in right side.

Now I want to update the **STOCK TABLE** and **ADD_PAYMENT TABLE** of the selected item as well as total price according to changes quantity in right side tabular form.

My three table MENU_ITEM,ADD_PAYMENT and STOCK table create script are given below.

```
CREATE TABLE  "MENU_ITEM" 
       ("M_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
        "ITEM_NAME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
        "PRICE" NUMBER(10,0), 
        "STOCK_STATUS" NUMBER(10,0), 
         CONSTRAINT "MENU_ITEM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("M_ID")
      USING INDEX  ENABLE
       )
    /
CREATE TABLE  "ADD_PAYMENT" 
       ("ID" NUMBER,
        "ORDER_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
        "M_ID" NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL, 
        "PRICE" NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL, 
        "QUANTITY" NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,  
        "TOTAL" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("PRICE"*"QUANTITY") VIRTUAL , 
         CONSTRAINT "ADD_PAYMENT_CON" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX  ENABLE
       )
    /
CREATE TABLE  "KITCHEN" 
       ("K_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
        "M_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, 
        "QUANTITY" NUMBER(10,0), 
         CONSTRAINT "KITCHEN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("K_ID")
      USING INDEX  ENABLE
       )
```

Comment: You can create view with instead-of trigger and region based on this view.

Comment: any helpful source?

Comment: http://rokitta.blogspot.ru/2009/12/tabular-forms-on-complex-views-using.html